# Array of List of array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am writing something like this. It seems `TreeMap<Double, List<double[]>[]> tm = new TreeMap<>();` doesn't work in my eclipse, because the code in `init` can recognize the data type I want. There are always errors. Can I do this? or how to do this kind of thing?

```
private static void init(TreeMap<Double, List<Double>[]> tm, List<double[]> ll) {
    for(double[] a:ll) {
        if(!tm.containsKey(a[0])) {
            List[] ab= new List[2];
            tm.put(new Double(a[0]),ab);
            tm.get(a[0])[0] = new LinkedList<double[]>();
            tm.get(a[0])[1] = new LinkedList<double[]>();
        }
        List<Double[]>[] b = tm.get(a[0]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TreeMap<Double, List<double[]>[]> tm = new TreeMap<>();
    List<double[]> ll = new LinkedList<>();
    ll.add(new double[] {-3,2.2});
    ll.add(new double[] {1,5.3});
    ll.add(new double[] {-1.3,4});
    ll.add(new double[] {8,22});
    init(tm,ll);
}
```

Comment: I do not suggest using `Double` as a map key. A rounding error will give you completely different results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List<double[]>[]` is not right. `List<T>` already indicates it is a list (or a collection in general) of `T`.

So, it must be `List<double[]>`

But, I see you are trying to pass a `TreeMap<Double, List<double[]>>` to 
`TreeMap<Double, List<Double[]>>` which won't work. The compiler cannot box (or unbox) a `double[]` to a `Double[]`. Make both consistent and it should work.

Comment: Can I put an array of list as value?

Comment: @WeihengLi By array of list, do you mean something like `List<Double>[]`. In this case, you cannot instantiate it as `new List<Double>[3]` as generic array creation is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void init(TreeMap<Double, List<double[]>[]> tm, List<double[]> ll) {
for(double[] a:ll) {
    if(!tm.containsKey(a[0])) {
        List[] ab= new List[2];
        tm.put(new Double(a[0]),ab);
        tm.get(a[0])[0] = new LinkedList<double[]>();
        tm.get(a[0])[1] = new LinkedList<double[]>();
    }
    List<double[]>[] b = tm.get(a[0]);

}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
TreeMap<Double, List<double[]>[]> tm = new TreeMap<>();
List<double[]> ll = new LinkedList<>();
ll.add(new double[] {-3,2.2});
ll.add(new double[] {1,5.3});
ll.add(new double[] {-1.3,4});
ll.add(new double[] {8,22});
init(tm,ll);
}
```

Comment: this code may help you.instead of using List<Double>[]> tm use List<double[]> 
   []> tm

Comment: Hi, try to add some more detail to your answer please. Posting just a "code-dump" is usually frowned upon here, even if the code provides the answer